# Decreasing fps on a small Three.js project

Tags: android, performance, google-chrome, three.js

I'm wrote a small Three.js program that is just supposed to show my
external model I built and imported with JSONLoader.

In using r-83, the problem is that this project works just fine on any laptop, but when I try to open it in my Samsung galaxy s6, the fps starts at about 60 fps, and from there it's downhill until it crushes.

I can't understand what am I doing wrong.

I uploaded it to my server at http://3dhd.co.il/test and also copied the code here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <link rel="icon" href="{{ URL::to('/images/favicon.png') }}" type="image/gif" sizes="16x16">

        <!-- Three.js r-83 scripts -->
        <script src="{{ asset('js/r-83/three.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/r-83/OrbitControls.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/HouseEditor/threeJS/js/libs/stats.min.js') }}"></script>
        <script src="{{ asset('js/HouseEditor/threeJS/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js') }}"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="Container" style="position: fixed; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></div>

        <script>
            var camera, scene, renderer, controls, mStats;
            initItem();

            function initItem()
            {
                scene = new THREE.Scene();
                camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(65, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 9000);
                camera.position.set(2, 380, 300);
                camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));

                var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xdddddd);
                scene.add(ambient);

                var aLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 0.05);
                aLight.position.copy(new THREE.Vector3(100, 900, 100));
                aLight.color.setHSL(0.1, 1, 0.95);
                scene.add(aLight);

                // Debugging tool
                window.scene = scene;

                // Create renderer
                renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ antialias: true, preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
                renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                renderer.setClearColor(0xffffff, 1);
                renderer.setPixelRatio( window.devicePixelRatio );

                var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
                loader.load(
                    '/3/kfir_closet01_foruv02.js',
                    function ( geometry, materials ) {
                        var material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
                        var object = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
                        scene.add( object );
                    }
                );

                var container = document.getElementById("Container");
                container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

                mStats = new Stats();
                mStats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
                mStats.domElement.style.zIndex = "100px";
                mStats.domElement.style.left = "0px";
                mStats.domElement.style.top = "0px";
                container.appendChild(mStats.domElement);

                // Create controls
                controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, container);
                controls.rotateSpeed = 0.7;
                controls.zoomSpeed = 1.2;
                controls.panSpeed = 0.8;
                controls.enableZoom = true;
                controls.enablePan = true;
                controls.enableDamping = true;
                controls.dampingFactor = 0.6;

                controls.minDistance = 100;
                controls.maxDistance = 450;
                controls.maxPolarAngle = 0.9 * Math.PI / 2;

                animateItem();
                window.addEventListener( 'resize', onItemWindowResize, false );
            }

            function animateItem()
            {
                requestAnimationFrame(animateItem);
                renderItem();
            }

            function renderItem()
            {
                mStats.update();
                renderer.render(scene, camera);
            }

            function onItemWindowResize()
            {
                camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
                camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
                renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see the code is pretty simple. So why doesn't it work on mobile phones?

Comment: Your code looks fine to me, and I don't see any memory leaks. Which browser are you using on mobile?

Comment: im using chrome (v 57).
on chrome it crushes, but if use my default samsung browser (called 'Browser") it works amazing at 60 fps